# Grid/Tile view with angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, jquery-masonry

I have 100 number of `div`s of 100px width, which can fit into a 250px width parent. Regardless of height, I need the `div`s to be displayed in rows, as shown in the picture. I have tried resolving this with css,and sadly I understood the reality.

[image]

Is there any **angularjs plugin** i can make use of?

I have heard about **jquery masonry**,is there any better option?

As @Divyanshu Maithani asked for a plunker with my current problem,
Please see the plunker link below in which i tried to solve my problem with angular-masonry

[image]

```
<div masonry>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="masonry-brick item">
      {{item.name}}
      <button class="toggle-button" ng-click="item.show=!item.show">show</button>
      <div ng-if="item.show" class="hidden-box">
        This is a hidden box for {{$index+1}}th item.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

***[Plunker DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/LCsciTpDt8FNFxqaziln?p=preview)***

And i am looking for other options also,since i don't want to end up my question with a jquery plugin like angular-masonry.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: here is an angular js masonary https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry plugin to work nicely with angular js

Comment: Although I managed to program such thing via PHP (3x3 in vertical count - not horizontal like yours) my vote (as advice) is for masonry. I used it in experimental stage at one project and its a great and very helpful plugin for what you need. I would not search for more, and I doubt you will find more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for [**AngularJS Masonry**](https://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/). You can see the demo at the homepage. And using it is simple using a `masonry-brick` class:

```
<div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

In order for your `masonry-brick` to not overlap with each other, you need to **`reload`** `masonry` whenever you `show` or `hide` an inner `div`. I've added a `function` to do so on `ng-click` which will also `broadcast` a `masonry.reload` event to reload the same.

Check [**this**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nZGbbZ9DhlCpaAxWkdMO?p=preview) working code.

**JS**

```
$scope.showItem = function(index) {
    $scope.items[index].show = !($scope.items[index].show);
    $scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div masonry>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="masonry-brick item">
      {{item.name}}
      <button class="toggle-button" ng-click="showItem($index)">show</button>
      <button class="toggle-button" ng-click="remove($index)">X</button>
      <div ng-if="item.show" class="hidden-box">
        This is a hidden box for {{$index+1}}th item.
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

There seems to be a problem due to the fact that `masonry` reloads instantly while the animation of the `masonry` transition takes time. I've added some transition duration and `$timeout` in [**this**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3EnrMXQlQR2VasrXRhr8?p=preview) plunk.

Comment: But my blocks are expandable.Meaning i have a hide & show block after my div.So it is getting overlapped, when using masonry

Comment: This should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.This looks like a 95% solution.But i am getting issue when clicking on show button multiple button spontaniuosly

Comment: `$scope.$broadcast('masonry.reload');` is not updating well.

Comment: if we click on show button fast ,the hidden div s are overlapped

Comment: please see image added on question.

Comment: If you check the link I've added, it seems to be working fine. As for *clicking on show button fast*, it seems to overlap for just a fraction of second before reloading. With some CSS, the animation can be made better I think.

Comment: Not for a fraction of second.when we click on show button fast ,it is getting stucked on the view i shown in question.

Comment: to get that issue.click fast on show button and stop before broadcast updates the view

Comment: The problem seems to be due to the fact that masonry reloads instantly while the animation of the masonry transition takes time. I've added some transition duration and `$timeout`. See this plunk and tell if it solves the problem for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/3EnrMXQlQR2VasrXRhr8?p=preview

Comment: This fix is ok.but not a 100%.breaking sometimes

Comment: I'll add this to the answer just in case. Hopefully there is a better workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible with Pure CSS and HTML. CSS 3 specifications provide for  `column-gap` & `column-width` property that makes it possible to define the gap between the columns.

Popular browsers have started supporting the same (`-webkit-column-width, -webkit-column-gap, -moz-column-width, -moz-column-gap` are all supported).

So the widths and gaps can be written in the following way:

```
#columns {
  -webkit-column-width: 220px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-width: 220px;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  column-width: 220px;
  column-gap: 15px;
}
```

I have made a fiddle which shows a working example. Works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/3cf9qrap/3/

Comment: But it is not keeping in order.ordered vertically.In my question i need to order div s horizontally

Comment: Oh okay, I went through the internet and found a couple of plugins that might meet your requirement. Check them out:
http://bragthemes.com/demo/pinstrap/ , 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example you looking for.Click the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/oK98KU95LjU0cu7YzjnZ?p=preview)

**Html/View**

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="item">
          {{item.name}}
   <button class="toggle-button" ng-click="item.show=!item.show">show</button>
          <div ng-if="item.show" class="hidden-box">
            This is a hidden box for {{$index+1}}th item.
          </div>
        </div>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: There is space between two divs.with your answer